# Getting the expected dimensions of the Jacobian with JAX?

Tags: python, jax, autodiff

I am trying to get the Jacobian for a simple parameterization function within JAX. The code is as follows:

```
# imports 
import jax 
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random

# simple parameterization function 
def reparameterize(v_params):
    theta = v_params[0] + jnp.exp(v_params[1]) * eps
    return theta
```

Suppose I initialize  `eps` to be a vector of shape `(3,)` and `v_params` to be of shape `(3, 2)`:

```
key = random.PRNGKey(2022)
eps = random.normal(key, shape=(3,))
key, _ = random.split(key)
v_params = random.normal(key, shape=(3, 2))
```

I want the Jacobian to be an array of shape `(3, 2)` but by using

```
jacobian(vmap(reparameterize))(v_params)
```

returns an array of shape `(3, 3, 3, 2)`. If I re-initialize with only a single `eps`:

```
key, _ = random.split(key)
eps = random.normal(key, shape=(1, ))
key, _ = random.split(key)
v_params = random.normal(key, shape=(2, ))
```

and call `jacobian(reparameterize)(v_params)` I get what I want, e.g., an array of shape `(2, )`. Effectively looping over all `eps` and stacking the results of each Jacobian gives me the desired Jacobian (and shape). What am I missing here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function `f` that maps an input of shape `shape_in` to an output of shape `shape_out`, the jacobian will have shape `(*shape_out, *shape_in)`.

In your case, `vmap(reparameterize)` takes an array of shape `(3, 2)` and returns an array of shape `(3, 3)`, so the output of the jacobian is an array of shape `(3, 3, 3, 2)`.

It's hard to tell from your question what computation you were intending, but if you want a jacobian the same shape as the input, you need a function that maps the input to a scalar. Perhaps the sum is what you had in mind?

```py
result = jacobian(lambda x: vmap(reparameterize)(x).sum())(v_params)
print(result.shape)
# (3, 2)
```